# How to change how table sections display themselves?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to display the sections in a UITableView different from the built-in behaviour, with images as the section header and footer. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement those UITableView-delegate methods:

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You can even mix custom and standard headers, if you return nil  in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: the tableView will use the standard section title if you provide one.